# pywin32-221-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, cmd, installation, pywin32

I ran

```
C:\Python34\Scripts\pip install C:\Python34\pywin32-221-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl
```

and command prompt gave back the message (I ran cmd as an admin)

```
pywin32-221-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I really have no idea how to solve this problem. I've looked at other answers for similar questions on the internet and all the solutions seem to be involved with downloading the right .whl file for the computer that they are installing the file on (64bit, right python version) but:

I'm using python 3.4 - "cp34"

this is what my python shell looks like when use platform.architecture()

```
import platform
platform.architecture()
('64bit', 'WindowsPE')"
```

my operating system is 64 bit

I already have pip installed

I tried every "cp34" version of the .whl files and all of them return the same error

Hope you can help! Thanks,
Sam

p.s I ran on cmd after I deleted the python31 files from my c drive:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>C:\Python34\Scripts\pip install C:\Python34\pywin32-221-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 257, in run
    InstallRequirement.from_line(name, None))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 172, in from_line
    return cls(req, comes_from, url=url, prereleases=prereleases)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 70, in __init__
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2606, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2544, in parse_requirements
    line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2512, in scan_list
    raise ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'C:\\Python34\\pywin32-221-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64', 'at', ':\\Python34\\pywin32-221-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64')

Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\ScHr0dZtEr\pip\pip.log
```

Comment: Is that the only Python version installed on your machine?

Comment: @kichik no I also have python 3.1 installed

Comment: WindowsPE is very restricted subset of normal Windows. Looks like pyWin32 can’t support it. What are you trying to do with pyWin32 on this OS?

Comment: I'm just trying to follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8BiOPBsXh0g&t=176s and he said to install that module (I'm not a hacker btw XD)

Comment: I don't know why I have Windows PE because Windows 10 is installed on my computer

Comment: Are you able to install anything (especially local *whl*s)? also where did you get the *whl* from? BTW: _Windows**PE**_ stands for *Portable Executable* which is fine.

Comment: I have installed pyautogui before using easyinstall. I got my .whl file from here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: I'm not sure on where to download local whls from but on the website that I downloaded pywin32 from it says "Use pip version 9 or newer to install the downloaded .whl files." so that might be the problem as in C:\Python34\Scripts on my computer there are only pip, pip3.4 and pip3 files

Comment: What if you download and install it from https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20221 ?